# How to override parameters of maven-war-plugin defined in parent pom.xml?

Tags: grails, maven, build, web.xml

I'm trying to build a grails project with maven. By itself, that wouldn't be so hard. But it is required that the `pom.xml` in my project have a certain enterprise pom as it's parent.

The parent pom has many things in it that are important in our deployment process here, but it also contains the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
    <webXml>webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I understand correctly, this tells maven to look for a `web.xml` file in `webapp/WEB-INF`. At this point, my project doesn't have a `web.xml` file, though it might later. How can I override this specification of the location of a `web.xml` file so that maven would:

1. Not look for a `web.xml` file at all.
2. Look for a `web.xml` file elsewhere.

As it is, after compiling and running tests, Maven reports:

```
Tests PASSED - view reports in target\test-reports
[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp[myapp] in [C:\code\workspace\myapp\myapp\target\myapp-current]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The specified web.xml file 'C:\code\workspace\myapp\myapp\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think that it is interesting, that the command being executed is `[war:war {execution: default-war}]` rather than `[grails:war]` or something. That might be relevant, also.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

Replace

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

with

```
<packaging>grails-app</packaging>
```